# Calling a new view: problems "hiding instance variable"

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, subview

I am trying to call a subview after a button is clicked on my root controller.  The warnings appear in my AppDelegate (code is below), but I included the method from my root controller on how I call this new subview also in case that too has a problem. 
the alerts that continue to come up are that the local declaration of navController hides an instance variable.
When I launch the application (which used to open fine) it now simply exits out...

```
#import "SEM2REDOAppDelegate.h"
#import "SEM2REDOViewController.h"

@implementation SEM2REDOAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize navController;


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Application lifecycle

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    SEM2REDOViewController  *firstController = [[SEM2REDOViewController alloc]
                                            initWithNibName:@"SEM2REDOViewController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController  *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                              initWithRootViewController:firstController];

    [self setNavContorller:navController];
    [window addSubview:[navController view]];

    [navController release];
    [firstController release];  

    return YES;
}
```

then here is the method inside of my first view controller

```
- (IBAction)chooseFirstMeeting:(id)sender {     
    SelectRotationController *selectView = [[SelectRotationController alloc] 
                                            initWithNibName:@"SelectView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [selectView.navigationItem setTitle:@"Select First Meeting"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.selectRotationController animated:YES];
    self.selectRotationController = selectView; 
    [selectView release];
}
```

I know this may be an extremely simple question but I've just started this. doing an intensive study on programming in high school as an added course so I'd really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename navController

```
UINavigationController  *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]
                                          initWithRootViewController:firstController];
```

into something else. You can do this automatically by control-clicking word "navController", choosing "Refactor" from context menu, and then "Rename...".

Explanation:

The problem, I believe, in your local variable navController having the same name as instance variable under synthesized declared property navController.

**Edit:**
Also, this seems to be a typo:

```
 [self setNavContorller:navController];
```

Correct:

```
 [self setNavController:navController];
```

Comment: Thanks! does it matter that in my .h file I have an @property with the UINavigationController *navController (should I change that also?)those alerts did go away!     now however the application launches but the button to bring up the second view simply exits the application? any ideas?

Comment: No, as long as you have only one navController at a time. The problem was in having two *different* variables sharing the same name.

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing the entire code, you can try activating console (shift-command-C or from the main Xcode menu View/Debug Area) and looking at the output after clicking that button.  Probably you will see an exception description there, which may help.

Comment: The console showed something helpful- the first time I clicked the button this message appeared "SEM2REDO[13487:b603] Application tried to push a nil view controller on target <UINavigationController: 0x4ea5be0>"

Comment: by clicking it again more complicated messages appeared "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/margueriteoquinn/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3/Applications/F2B86CC5-C700-414E-9030-17E94535EB1A/SEM2REDO.app> (loaded)' with name 'SelectView''
*** Call stack at first throw:......
terminate called throwing an exception" if you have any advice that'd would be fantastic but thank you so much for your help already.

Comment: [self setNavContorller:navController] – this looks like a typo.